# Stop Bash Script after a Particular Interval

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -l /bin/bash
ls -l /sbin/bash
ls -l /usr/local/bin/bash
ls -l /usr/bin/bash
ls -l /usr/sbin/bash
ls -l /usr/local/sbin/bash
```

**After running this script I want to stop this script If time is more than 60 seconds.
Assume 1st commands execute in 10 and second commands take 50 seconds after that I have to stop the execution of the script.**

Comment: Why should the script take more than 60 seconds? These are just a few `ls` commands.

Comment: @hek2mgl Interesting spot. Just assume so.

Comment: If one of the directories is really big, it could take a significant time on some platforms (Linux at the very least). The system call is non-blocking, so a timeout won't necessarily be able to interrupt it.

Comment: its just an example..commands will change..in real world scenario

Comment: Bad example then.

Comment: its not bad example @hek2mgl try to think in generic way.

Comment: @tripleee You mean the *system call is blocking*, right? Because that was my point.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`timeout(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout)

```
timeout 60 ./your_script.sh
```

Or kill it afterwards:

```
./your_script.sh & :
sleep 60 && kill $!
```

Comment: without timeout?

Comment: @NicK Nope. I don't know anything else. Maybe kill it afterwards.

Comment: I am not linux expert thats why i am facing this issue... I know the way in first line capture the current time and after executing each command check in if else if it exceeds more than time expected. kill the process.. killing command also in the else section of each commands.